# How do I convert ANTsR to ANTsPy image querying command?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to convert the following ANTsR line to ANTsPy:

`seggm[seggm < 0.5 & tmp > 0.5] <- 2`  (seggm and tmp are both 'ANTsImage's)

I have tried:

`seggm[seggm.numpy() < 0.5 & tmp.numpy() > 0.5] = 2` but this is too slow.. Is there a faster way to perform this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whoops typed it differently in my code.. This works now!